# What if I create configurations in simple product?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product

What will happen if I create configurations inside a simple product? Will the simple product switch into configurable product by itself?

Answer (score 1):

Magento default provides this but it will prompt you to add attributes to the attribute set which you have used to create simple product with configurations. e.g. https://nimb.ws/XBp7Uo

You need to add attributes in attribute set which you have used and then it will converted into configurable product.